# SwiftUI How to Have a ForEach loop iterate based on how many days of a selected month in a Picker is

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

So I created a line of code that takes two values, a year and a month, and depending on what values you give it, it will calculate the number of days in a given month for a given year. Initially I was going to use State variables so it would just update automatically, but because of how Structs work, I couldn't use the variables I had just barely initialized. (as in the "Cannot use instance member 'year' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" Error). The reason I want this code is because I want a forEach Loop to automatically iterate based on that number (as the app I am making will have a list for every day for the next two years). Here is my code:

```
struct YearView: View {

@State var year = [2020, 2021, 2022]
//monthSymbols gets an array of all the months
@State var monthArray = DateFormatter().monthSymbols!
@State var yearIndex = 0
@State var monthIndex = 0
@State var month = 0
@State var daysInMonth = Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month + 1))!)!.count

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        
        List {
            Section {
                VStack {
                    Picker("Years", selection: $yearIndex) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< year.count) { index in
                            Text(String(self.year[index])).tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    
                    
                    Divider()
                    
                    if yearIndex == 0 {
                        Picker("Month", selection: $monthIndex) {
                            ForEach(6 ..< monthArray.count) { index in
                                Text(self.monthArray[index]).tag(index)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 2)
                    } else {
                        Picker("Month", selection: $monthIndex) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< monthArray.count) { index in
                                Text(self.monthArray[index]).tag(index)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 2)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(day: dayData[i])) {
                        DayRow(day: dayData[i])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("\(monthArray[monthIndex + indexTest]) \(String(year[yearIndex]))"))
    }
    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
}
```

}

The ForEach loop that is by the Navigation Link is the one I want to be iterated. I have tried creating a function as such:

```
func getRange(year: Int, month: Int) -> Int {
return Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month + 1))!)!.count
```

}

I'm not sure where I would run that however, if that would even work. I'm new to SwiftUI and GitHub, so if there's any more info I can give that would help, just ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you should be able to call your getRange(year:, month:) function in your ForEach. Passing in `yearIndex` and `monthIndex`.

I wrote up this little sample code to quickly test the theory. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

-Dan

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var year = 3
    @State private var month = 2


    var body: some View {
         List {
            ForEach(0 ..< getRange(year: year, month: month)) { i in
                Text("\(i)")
            }
        }

    }

    func getRange(year: Int, month: Int) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month + 1))!)!.count
    }
}
```

edit to address the question in your comment;

To update your Picker label properly try changing your code to this:

```
Picker("Years", selection: $year) {
    ForEach(0 ..< year) { index in
        Text("\(index)")
    }
}
```

See if that gives you the desired response. It's not what you're doing is entirely wrong, I'm just not super clear on what your ultimate intent is. But play around with the code, I think you're on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I wasn't aware that you could input functions in for loops- so I've done that, and it works for the most part! The only thing is, when I change the value of the monthIndex / yearIndex variable using the picker, it doesn't update the forEach loop values that are being displayed- any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: I updated the code to possibly address your question here.